# If you apply a unitary transformation to an entangled state, is it still entangled?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, unitarity, linear-algebra

See title. If this is not true, is there a counter example? If it is not true, does it hold true for certain combinations of unitaries and entangled states?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The state $|\psi \rangle = \dfrac{|00\rangle + |11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$ is a maximal entangled state that can be created by applying the unitary transformation $U_1 = CNOT \cdot (H \otimes I) $ to the state $|\psi_{init}\rangle = |00\rangle$.

Then now if we apply the unitary transformation $U_2 = U_1^{-1} = (H \otimes I) \cdot CNOT $ to the state $|\psi\rangle$ then we will get back $|\psi_{init} \rangle = |00\rangle$ which is a product state (non-entangled state) by definition.

However, if you only applied unitaries that only acts on a single qubit, for instance $U_2 = X \otimes X$, then it would still have been an entangled state. This is because entanglement does not change under local unitary operations.

A proof for why local unitary operations do not change entanglement is as follows:

Say you are in some entangled state, $|\psi_e \rangle$ by applying a unitary $U$ to some arbitrary starting state, and then apply local unitary operations, call them $A \otimes B$, to $|\psi_e \rangle$ and get a state  $|\psi_n \rangle = (A \otimes B)|\psi_e \rangle$ that is not entangled, then you could express that state as a tensor product $|\psi_n \rangle = A(c_1|0 \rangle + c_2|1 \rangle) \otimes B(c_3|0 \rangle + c_4|1 \rangle)$. Applying the inverses of $A$ and $B$ to the respective bits of $|\psi_n \rangle$, should then yield the original entangled state as a tensor product, however it shouldn't be possible to represent it as a tensor product since it is entangled.

Comment: would something like $X \otimes Y$ also preserve entanglement?

Comment: "entanglement does not change under local unitary operations" is there a proof for that?

Comment: Yes, $X \otimes Y$ is still preserve the entanglement. Note that this maps the state $\psi \rangle = \dfrac{-i|00\rangle + i|11\rangle}{\sqrt{2}} $ thus still an entangled state. I am sure there is a proof that you can find. The way I see it is that $U = A \otimes B$ only amount to local changes of the basis. Since $(A\otimes B) \sum \lambda_i |a_i \rangle \otimes |b_i\rangle = \sum \lambda_i A|a_i\rangle \otimes B|b_i \rangle $.

Comment: ok. i came up with a proof. see my edit to your answer.